# How to approach multi-million data selection

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

I have a table that stores specific updates for all customers.

Some sample table:

`record_id | customer_id | unit_id | time_stamp | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | more`

When I created the application, I did not realize how much this table would grow -- currently I have over 10mil records within 1 month. I am facing issues, when php stops executing due to amount of time it takes. Some queries produce top-1 results, based on the `time_stamp` + `customer_id` + `unit_id`

How would you suggest handling this type of issues? For example, I can create new table for each customer, although I think it does not a good solution.

I am stuck with no good solution in mind.

Comment: Paste your tables structure along with the SQL that retrieves the data(you already have that part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the cloud (where you're charged for moving data between server and db), ignore.

**Move all logic to the server**

The fastest query is a `SELECT` `WHERE`ing the `PRIMARY`.  It won't matter how large your database is, it will come back just as fast with a table of 1 row (as long as your hardware isn't unbalanced).

I can't tell exactly what you're doing with your query, but first download all of the sorting and limiting data into PHP.  Once you've got what you need, `SELECT` the data directly `WHERE`ing on `record_id` (I assume that's your `PRIMARY`).

It looks like your on demand data is pretty computationally intensive and huge, so I recommend using a faster language.  http://blog.famzah.net/2010/07/01/cpp-vs-python-vs-perl-vs-php-performance-benchmark/

Also, when you start sorting and limiting on the server rather than the db, you can start identifying shortcuts to speed it up even further.

This is what the server's for.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use partitioning of your data following some criteria.

You can make horizontal or vertical partition of your data.

For example group your customer_id in 10 partitions, using his id module 10.

So, customer_id terminated in 0 goes to partition 0, with ended in 1 goes to partition 1

[MySQL can make this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) for you easily.

Answer (score 0):

What is the count of records within the tables?  Often, with relational databases, it's not how much data you have (millions are nothing to relational databases), it's how you're retrieving it.

From the look of your select, in fact, you probably just need to optimize the statement itself and avoid the multiple subselects, which is probably the main cause of the slowdown.  Try running an explain on that statement, or just get the ids and run the interior select individually on the ids of the records that you've actually found & retrieved in the first run.

Just the fact that you have those subselects within your overall statement  means that you haven't optimized that far into the process anyway.  For example, you could be running a nightly or hourly cron job that aggregates into a new table the sets like the one created by `SELECT gps_unit.idgps_unit`, and then you can run your selects against a **previously generated table** instead of creating blocks of data that are equivalent of a table on the fly.

If you find yourself unable to effectively optimize that select statement, you have "final" options like:

- Categorize via some criteria and split into different tables.
- Keep a deep archive, such that anything past the first year or so is migrated to a less used table and requires special retrieval.
- Finally, if you have so much small data, you may be able to completely archive certain tables and keep them around in file form only and then truncate past a certain date.  Often with web tracking data that isn't that important and is kinda spammy, I end up doing this after a few years, when the data is really not going to do anyone any good any more.